# how to find ssl.conf file in apache

Tags: apache, openssl, virtualhost

I am trying to install self signed ssl on IP address. I have apache in centos7. I have mod_ssl installed. I have been able to create self signed certificate with openssl req. Now I need to add this certificate to virtual hosts. I found two different files in tutorials for this purpose.
etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf and second option is etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.
But I could find apache2 folder in etc but not sites-availabe and no httpd in etc. Where do I find the relevant file to edit virtual hosts?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can just create the folder sites-available if you want inside of the Apache folder. The important thing is to check the Main Apache Config file and make sure that it is loading up the default-ssl.conf file. Usually its done by putting an Include /*. That would load up everything in that folder.

Comment: Thank you. No I do not want any folder. I need to find virtual hosts so that I can add my self signed certificate. How do I do that?

Comment: depending on which Distribution you are using, running one of these commands would show you which Vhost has been loaded by apache. 
# apache2ctl -S   [On Debian/Ubuntu]
# apachectl -S    [On CentOS/RHEL]
OR
# httpd -S
this would show you the path to the vhost. if nothing shows up, you would need to create your own vhost and include it in the main apache config to include the file. Then restart Apache

Answer (score 0):

Config files for Apache under Centos should be at /etc/httpd/ instead of /etc/apache/